# Best practices for API response status codes

Tags: http, httprequest, http-status-codes, api-design

I am building an API and I am returning this kind of status codes for each method (e.g., "register_user"):

- `200` (OK) when the user has been registered successfully
- `403` (forbidden) when there are missing parameters in the request
- `409` (conflict) when a user was already registered

In addition to the status code, I return a "message" field explaining what happened. Do you consider returning these codes in this example a good practice? Or should I return 200 in all of them but an error in the "message" field?

Comment: Since the situation is not OK, you shouldn't return 200

Comment: Take a look at this resource http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html. You should look at 400 - Bad Request for when there are missing parameters.

Answer (score 0):

> The 403 (Forbidden) status code indicates that the server understood
> the request but refuses to authorize it.  A server that wishes to
> make public why the request has been forbidden can describe that
> reason in the response payload (if any).

-- [RFC 7231, 6.5.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3)

That doesn't sound like what you've got at all. The other two are reasonable. Missing parameters are typically handled with a 400 response code.